# How to port-forward my Sagemcom Broadband SAS router?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am unable to port forward a port on my router, although I have no firewall or antivirus enabled. I used websites like https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, https://portchecker.co/, and canyouseeme.org/ to check whether port 22 was open. They all say it is closed. I tried a few different ports, I always get the same result.

[image: Port-forwarding port 22 screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a server listening on that port?

Comment: What's using ssh? When you say your firewall is off, your talking about the OS right? NAT / Firewall is pretty much synonymous on consumer routers. It's needs to be on to port forward if we are talking about the routers firewall.

Comment: You can use nmap or a similar tool on your local network, from a another computer scan the first 100 ports or so. Once you see it open on the local side, port forwarding shouldn't be a hassle.

Comment: You may want to enter 22 in the “External Port End” field. // Also, as the others mentioned: Having the port “open” is not enough. On the `192.168.1.13` machine, the SSH service needs to be running and reachable. // Also, please check your external IP address as reported by the router. Is it perhaps in a private address range or inside 100.64.0.0/10?